# Dropbox paid account that has email deleted

Tags: email, dropbox, account-recovery

**In brief**

How to recover Dropbox account that has email deleted?

**Details**

I have purchased my Dropbox account to Plus and been using it and love it.

Until last month, the email account I used with this Dropbox account get deleted/inactivated due to my leave with previous job.

So now my email not there for me to handle the switching and/or take back my ownership with my Dropbox account.

My question is, how to recover Dropbox account that has email deleted?

It's urgent to me. Any hint to resolve my case is highly appreciated!

p.s.

I have contacted with Dropbox via email to ask for support but for quite a long time, I get no response so I ask here.

p.s. 2nd

I still have the previous downloaded files/folders on my laptop

Answer (score 2):

There are significant security issues associated with this - all designed to protect your data.

If you can’t sign in to your email account, try contacting your email service provider (ESP) for assistance. Only your ESP can help you regain access to your email account. Dropbox is not an ESP, and can’t contact ESPs on your behalf.

If your ESP is able to help you regain access, you can then request a password reset link for your Dropbox account.

Useful References:

https://help.dropbox.com/accounts-billing/settings-sign-in/lost-email-access

https://help.dropbox.com/accounts-billing/settings-sign-in/password-reset

https://help.dropbox.com/accounts-billing/settings-sign-in/lost-email-access

[Contact Dropbox Support](https://help.dropbox.com/teams-admins/team-member/customer-support-levels)

Comment: Thank you for the hint. The email is deleted by the ESP you are sharing... So I don't think I could do anything with the ESP.

Comment: If that addresses your issue, please consider marking it as accepted to make it easier for others with a similar issue to find the references. Thanks.

Comment: No it is not solving my issue. Thanks